# First Unique Character In a String-Leetcode

Tags: java, string, for-loop, if-statement

I have tried out *[387.First Unique Character In A string](https://leetcode.com/problems/first-unique-character-in-a-string/)*

> Given a string s, find the first non-repeating character in it and
> return its index. If it does not exist, return -1.

> ***EXAMPLE : 1***
>
> ```
>  Input: s = "leetcode"
>  
>  Output: 0
> ```
>
> ***EXAMPLE :2***
>
> ```
>  Input: s = "loveleetcode"
>
>  Output: 2
> ```

I have been trying this problem. I thought we will pick one by one all the characters and check if a repeating character exists break from the loop. And if not then return that index.I have thought over a solution which I believe is not the most efficient way but I want to know the how can I solve this problem with the approach given below:

```
public int firstUniqChar(String s) {
  for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
      for(int j=i+1;j<s.length();j++){
          if(s.charAt(i)==s.charAt(j)){
              break;
          }
          
      }
      
  }
    return -1;
}
```

I'm confused how to return the index.I'm unable to find the logic after:

```
for(int j=i+1;j<s.length();j++){
              if(s.charAt(i)==s.charAt(j)){
                  break;
              }
              
          }
```

If anyone can help me find out the logic here.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a flag variable.

```
 public int firstUniqChar(String s) {
     int flag=0;
     for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        flag=0;
        for(int j=0;j<s.length();j++){
            if(s.charAt(i)==s.charAt(j) && i!=j){
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag==0){
            return i;
        } 
    }
   return -1;
}
```

Comment: It is passing 75/108 test cases but still failing with some

Comment: Input:"aabb" Expected output: -1

Comment: You can change the 2nd for loop

Comment: I have edited the above code. Have a look at it. I think it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public static int firstUniqChar(String s) {
    L: for (int i = 0, length = s.length(); i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
            if (i != j && s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j))
                continue L;
        return i;
    }
    return -1;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(firstUniqChar("leetcode"));
    System.out.println(firstUniqChar("loveleetcode"));
    System.out.println(firstUniqChar("aabb"));
}
```

output:

```
0
2
-1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 26 possible lowercase English letters, so you could use two 26 element arrays.

One array, `letterCount`, keeps counts of each letter.  Start at 0 and add 1 every time the corresponding letter appears in the text string.  The second array, `position`, holds the position of the first occurrence of that letter, or -1 if the letter never appears.  You will need to initialise that array to -1 for all elements.

Process the string in order, recording initial positions, once only for each letter, and incrementing the count for each letter in the string.

After the string has been processed, look through the `letterCount` array.  If there are no letters with a 1 count then return -1.  If exactly one letter has a 1 count, then return the position of that letter from the `position` array.  If more than one letter has a 1 count, then pick the one with the lowest value for its position.

Using two loops is a highly inefficient way of solving this problem.  The string can be up to 100,000 characters long and you are processing it multiple times.  Far better to process it only once, keeping track of what you have found so far.

Answer (score 0):

#### Fix you code

You need to add a variable that tells you if you have breaked the loop or not

```
static int firstUniqChar(String s) {
    boolean duplicate;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        duplicate = false;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < s.length(); j++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)) {
                duplicate = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!duplicate) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

#### Improve

There is a smarter way, that is finding the last index occurence of the current char, if it's equal to the current index : that char is unique and you return its index

```
static int firstUniqChar(String s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.lastIndexOf(s.charAt(i)) == i) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: The first code is failing with some test cases as mentioned input="aabb" expected output should be -1 whereas the output coming is 1

Comment: I think the second code has the same error because the same case is failing

Answer (score 0):

If you do not bother about time complexity using IdenxOF operations, then one can try this solution.

> **indexOf()** – also runs in linear time. It iterates through the internal array and checking each element one by one. So the time
> complexity for this operation always requires O(n) time.

```
int firstUniqCharOneLoop(String str) {
            for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                if (str.indexOf(str.charAt(i))== str.lastIndexOf(str.charAt(i)) ) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The lowest complexity I managed to achieve:

```
public class UniqueSymbolFinder {
    static int findFirstUniqueChar(String s) {
        Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>(s.length());
        List<CharWithIndex> candidates = new LinkedList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char ch = s.charAt(i);
            CharWithIndex charWithIndex = new CharWithIndex(ch, i);
            
            if (set.add(ch)) {
                candidates.add(charWithIndex);
            } else {
                candidates.remove(charWithIndex);
            }
        }
        return candidates.size() == 0 ? -1 : candidates.get(0).index;
    }

    /**
     * Class for storing the index. 
     * Used to avoid of using an indexOf or other iterations.
     */
    private static class CharWithIndex {
        int index;
        char ch;

        private CharWithIndex(char ch, int index) {
            this.ch = ch;
            this.index = index;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            CharWithIndex that = (CharWithIndex) o;
            return ch == that.ch;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(ch);
        }
    }
}
```

I believe the memory usage can still be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

#### 100% Correct JAVA Solution

Since the question is about returning the index of the first non-repeating character in a string, we need some data structure to save the index of each character in the string for us.

I choose here the [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) of Java. Basically, what you can do with it, you can save a pair of values (or pair of other data structures).

So, in my solution, I am saving a **Character** **Integer** pair. The first is considered as a key (here it is **each character** in the string), and the second is its **index value**.

The problem here is that we only want to keep the minimum index of **non-repeating** characters and that's why if you take a look below, you will find the **maxIndexForRepeatedValues** is set to be **10** power **5** as the input constraint says **1 <= s.length <= 10 power 5**.

However, I am using that value to neglect repeated characters that would be found in the **HashMap** and at the end, we retrieve the minimum index which is the index of course for the first character from the map, or if there were only repeated characters, we return **-1**.

To make the code shorter, I used [ternary-operator](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-ternary-operator) but you can write it with **if-else** if you want!

```
class Solution {
    public int firstUniqChar(String s) {

        int maxIndexForRepeatedValues = 100000;
        Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++) {

            char key = s.charAt(i);
            int resIndex = map.containsKey(key) ? maxIndexForRepeatedValues : i;
            map.put(key, resIndex);

        }

        int minIndex = Collections.min(map.values());
        return minIndex == maxIndexForRepeatedValues ? -1 : minIndex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Solution {
    public int firstUniqChar(String s) {
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        char current =s.charAt(i);
        if(s.indexOf(current)==s.lastIndexOf(current)){
            return i;
        }
        }
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: here is a java code

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**